# C#. Sending byte[] via email and then retrieve it

Tags: c#, arrays

What would be the best way to do the following in order?

1. get a string out of a byte[]
2. send this string via email.
3. Import the string.
4. Get the byte[] back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you can only use text, base64-encode the string:

```
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(binary);
...
byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
```

See the [`System.Net.Mail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) namespace for built-in mail classes in .NET.

However, is there any reason you can't attach it to the mail as a binary attachment, and let the mail code handle the conversion for you?

Comment: Is there something you don't know?!